# Convert Hours and Minutes into Milliseconds and return into HH:mm:ss Format

Tags: java, datetime, time

Using `TimeUnit` I wanted to Convert `Hours` and `Minutes` into `Milliseconds` with the below code:

```
int hours = 01, minutes = 0; 
long milliseconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes));
```

Works Fine with `3600000` milliseconds

And using `SimpleDateFormat` to return into `HH:mm:ss` format:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
String returnFormat = formatter.format(date); //Final Result.
```

and this give me a result of `09:59:59` which is not the expected output.

I am confused, what's wrong with the code above? I am expecting `01:00:00` output.

**UPDATE:**

Actually I am using the above code to create a simple countdown timer using `Handler post.delayed` function.

```
...
@Override
public void run() {
    milliseconds -= 1000; //Remove 1 Seconds
    handler.postDelayed(this,1000); //Delay in 1 Seconds
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); //Create Time Formatting
    Date date = new Date(milliseconds); //Put the milliseconds into Format
    String returnFormat = formatter.format(date)); 
    Log.w("COUNTDOWN", returnFormat);
}
```

Comment: I was expecting about that. The `3600000` is a duration (1 hour in millis) it is not the amount of ms since the start of the unix epoch. Which is what `new Date()` expects. And there is also some nice time zoning involved probably.

Comment: Why don't you format it yourself if you already have the values for hours and minutes? Something like `String.format( "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes )`. Also note that `hours = 01,` is octal notation, i.e. you can't write `08` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of your timezone is different. By making the timezone GMT you will be able to gain the expected result. Use the following code snippet.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String returnFormat = formatter.format(date); //Final Result.
System.out.println(returnFormat);
```